# Is Parent Group required on multisites?

Tags: groups, multisite

When I edit a group, it will not allow me to save unless I select a Parent group. Is Parent Group required? If a Parent Group was accidentally assigned, how do you remove it without assigning a new Parent?

CiviCRM 4.7.9 and WP

This image shows an example of a Group that does not have a Parent Group. When I edit the Group the settings, the Parent pull-down list is automatically populated with a group called "Not Used (Smart Group)". It is not possible to deselect or select "none". Also, there is an asterisk next to the parent group indicating that it is required.

[image]

The second image shows a Group that has a Parent, and I would like to remove this relationship. But it is not possible. When I try to remove the Parent and save I receive an error message that Parent Group is required.

[image]

Comment: This shouldn't be the case.  Please update your question with a screenshot (and CiviCRM version) so folks can better help you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you're using CiviCRM in a multisite configuration.  You may want to update this question and future questions to reflect that.  Relatively few folks use it, and it affects the answer to this question.

There is also a [multisite extension][1 that can be used to control further permissions with regards to this.

In short - you don't normally need a parent group, but with multisite, you do.  There's details on why [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/multisite/).

Comment: I did not know that - must make it a habit to read all of Jon's answers!

Comment: You are amazing. We've been trying to fix this problem for a while now and this fixed it.  We have a multi-lingual website and we tried to use CiviCRM's multi-site configuration for our directory listings, but could not get it to work. So we no longer needed it to be turned on. I just turned it off and our parent group problem is solved!!  Thank you so much. So grateful!

Answer (score 0):

interestingly we hit this issue recently too. Not because we were actually using multisite, but because we had 'enabled' it so that we had the 'Associated Organisation' field available to us to help connect individuals to groups (ie show the User which were 'their groups' based on their relationship to an Organisation, and that Organisations 'association' with a Group.

I believe this is the relevant PR https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19122

Comment: Ah - should have read your comment on Jon's. Anyway, there is a potential fix for this ;-)